# pfgplots plot in degrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, degrees

Everywhere on the web, and in this forum, tells me pfgplot plots trig functions in degrees, which is what I'm after.

Here is the code for my graph:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    domain=1:20000,
    xmode=log,
    xlabel=Frequency (Hz),
    ylabel=Phase shift (\degree),
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none, samples=100, red] function {atan(-2*pi*0.001*x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Transfer function with multiple values of $RC$}
\end{figure}
```

And the result, which as you can see, is in radians (otherwise it would stretch to minus 90).
[image: result]

How can I plot in degrees?

Comment: Your arguments for atan make little since.

Comment: @JohnKormylo they make a lot of sense when you're analyzing the phase of a passive filter...

Comment: Right, the 2\pi is to convert frequency from Hz to redians.  So the ratio of imaginary and real amplitudes is actually S for this case (pure inductor).

Comment: Nah 2\pi is angular frequency to Hz :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `\addplot [...] function {...}` it uses `gnuplot` on the terminal, which uses radians for trigonometric functions, as noted in Section 4.3.5 of the [`pgfplots` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots).

To use the `pgf` computation engine, remove the word `function` (or replace it with `expression`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    domain=1:20000,
    xmode=log,
    xlabel=Frequency (\si{\hertz}),
    ylabel=Phase shift (\si{\degree}),
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none, samples=100, red] {atan(-2*pi*0.001*x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]